# Why don't custom events show up in Blend for a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I have created a UserControl, and added a couple of custom routed events.

The problem is these events only show up in Properties->Events when I am manipulating an instance on the art board.

If I am editing the UserControl itself, the my custom events do not show up in the Events panel.

Is this a limitation of Blend, or a side effect of how UserControls work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think i've found my own answer:

Sounds like its a limitation of Blend.

According to Dr. WPF

> Blend always creates an instance of
>   the base class as the root designer
>   element.

See threads here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8a61c5b0-32a9-4ae2-bcf0-f0eddf0efded/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cbaaba59-2a90-4806-b3bd-9e4bce3741e0/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7e507c2a-6ac4-4ed6-9b7f-abb15310d04f